# Different behavior of ExtJS application in debug and minified mode

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm facing an strange behavior in an web application I'm currently working on. The interface is totally built with ExtJs 4. The application has two modes, Debug and Production.

In Debug mode, when user click a menu item, I load synchronously, the dependent Javascripts file. Something like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i &lt; config.dependency.length; i++ ) {
   var element = document.createElement('script');

   element.onload = callback;
   element.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if ( element.readyState == 'loaded' || element.readyState == 'complete' ) {
         callback();
      }
   };
}
```

One of the module's javascript file is like this:

module.js

```
Ext.define('Company.view.system.Module', {
   extend: 'Company.view.abstract.Panel', 
   alias: 'widget.system.module', 

   /**
    * These "_items" are built into the Object in `Company.view.abstract.Panel`
    * using: Ext.create(this._items[i].clazz, conf);
    *
    * I'm just omitting the whole business logic there
    */
   _items: [{
      flex: 2, 
      clazz: 'Company.view.system.module.Form'
   }, {
      flex: 5, 
      clazz: 'Company.view.system.module.HtmlEditor'
   }]
});

Ext.define('Company.view.system.module.Form', {
   extend: 'Company.view.abstract.Form', 
   alias: 'widget.system.module.form', 

   items: [{
      xtype: 'fieldset', 
      title: 'Module Grid', 

      items: [{
         xtype: 'system.module.grid'
      }]
   }]
});

Ext.define('Company.view.system.module.Grid', {
   extend: 'Company.view.abstract.Grid', 
   alias: 'widget.system.module.grid', 

   columns: [{
      ...
   }], 

    afterLayout: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        alert('after layout');
    }
});

Ext.define('Company.view.system.module.HtmlEditor', {
   extend: 'Company.view.abstract.HtmlEditor', 
   alias: 'widget.system.module.htmleditor', 

   ...
});
```

Everything's working as expected in Debug mode. But in Production mode, I load the whole Modules as a single generated-minified-obfuscated javascript file (modules.js) at start up (i.e. before the ViewPort is rendered), instead of loading dependent modules after menu click event.

In Production mode, every Items, which is instantiated using "xtype" (Company.view.system.module.Grid in the above sample), is not rendered at all!

Screenshots of [Debug mode](http://yellowcluster.net/files/pic/debug-mode.png) and [Production Mode](http://yellowcluster.net/files/pic/production-mode.png).

What do you think is going on here which I'm missing?


**Update:**
The problem lies with the `Height` of the GridPanel, as It was computed at runtime, from the browser's screen size. Hence when the component being instantiated, the Height was not computed yet! Silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try moving the system.module.grid definition before it's being used in the system.module.form.

Comment: nothing! It's just simply won't render the sub-items. I just checked it now, and strange enough that even the Store of the Grid is working and I can see XHR log in the console

Comment: since the "same" code works in dev my focus would be on timing of the xtype definitions. they have to be defined before they are used by the create method. can you verify that your code is actually loaded in to the browser by spitting out some log statements?

Comment: I've updated the sample code above, and added `afterLayout` method. It is called to. and I'm getting 2-3 alerts on screen

Comment: so you are saying it does get loaded properly? If so get a an eval version of Illuminations for Developers firebug plugin and see what's up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the module.grid code is loaded properly, and being rendered. I receive both `afterRender` and `afterLayout` event, but it's not being shown. Even the store of the grid is loaded afterwards as well.

Comment: the plugin i referred to will let you examine your extjs components and their state. it will highlight their page location and lots of other good info to help u debug.

Comment: Thank you for the plugin you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise from having two different versions. What's your reason for that?

Comment: Well, it's not two different versions actually. In development, I just  write the application with lots of comments and indention and etc. and deploy it on the server. Then I will execute a bash script, and minify and obfuscate everything on the server. The application then pick up the files and merge them into a single file, and ship it to client

Comment: Why don't you use Sencha SDK to minified it on your machine? These will be two effectively same versions I think

Comment: I'm referring to delayed load of files you have in the Debug environment.

Comment: yes, precisely. There is a lot of delay in loading, say 70 files, in debug mode. But eventually it won't happen on the server, and specially not to the end user. And beside that, I'm considering to implement a password-protected debug version on server for development purpose too. So it might come handy in future as well.